# Method reference for array Object[]::new

Tags: java, java-8

Below is my code:

```
Random rand = new Random();
String[] randomstrs  = new String[3];
randomstrs = Arrays.stream(randomstrs)
    .map(e -> Arrays.toString(rand.ints(3, 0, 5).toArray()).replaceAll("\\[|\\]", ""))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
    .toArray(String[0]::new); // compile error
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(randomstrs));
```

I would like to know how can we use method reference at line `.toArray(String[0]::new);`. I understand that we can do `new String[0]` but I am more interested in using a method reference. Any pointers?

Comment: Method reference should be applied to a type. `String[0]` is not a type, it's a built array size `0`. `String[]` is is a type.

Comment: Hmm, its not a method. Thanks :)

Comment: Why collect to a list if you want an array? btw, I haven't downvoted

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Because `.map(...).toArray(new String[0])` fails.

Comment: You have to pass an `IntFunction` to `Stream.toArray`, in your case `String[]::new`, or `size -> new String[size]` if it's more readabe to you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either remove `collect()` and generate an array from the `Stream` directly:

```
randomstrs = 
    Arrays.stream(randomstrs)
          .map(e -> Arrays.toString(rand.ints(3, 0, 5).toArray()).replaceAll("\\[|\\]", ""))
          .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Note that `Stream::toArray` expects an `IntFunction<A[]>`, which means a functional interface having a method that accepts an `int` parameter and returns an array of the relevant type. When you pass a method reference (such as `String[]::new`), you don't pass the argument of the method (which in this case is the length of the array).

Or, if you want to collect the `Stream` to a `List` and then convert it to an array, you should pass an array instance to that method, not a functional interface. Therefore you would need to write:

```
randomstrs = 
    Arrays.stream(randomstrs)
          .map(e -> Arrays.toString(rand.ints(3, 0, 5).toArray()).replaceAll("\\[|\\]", ""))
          .collect (Collectors.toList())
          .toArray(new String[0]);
```

Comment: It's not two terminal operations. That's impossible. It's one terminal operation and [`List.toArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray-T:A-).

Comment: Can you explain why `.toArray(new String[0])` failed?

Comment: @roundAbout `.toArray(new String[0])` works. `.toArray(String[0]::new)` fails.

Comment: @roundAbout, the two methods have similar names, but they accept different things depending on which object the methods are on. Method on `Collection` accepts `new String[0]`. Method on `Stream` accepts `String[]::new`.

Answer (score 0):

There’s more questionable in your code than the way you’re creating the array. The first array you’re creating via `new String[3]` is entirely unused. You are overwriting its reference with a reference to a new array created subsequently, so you only use the array to tell the stream to do three iterations. An alternative would be using `IntStream.range`:

```
String[] randomstrs = IntStream.range(0, 3)
    .mapToObj(e -> Arrays.toString(rand.ints(3, 0, 5).toArray()).replaceAll("\\[|\\]", ""))
    .toArray(String[]::new); // compile error
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(randomstrs));
```

Of course, if all you’re interested in, is the `String` representation, you can `collect` the values to a `String` in the first place. You also can use the same `Collector` in the embedded operation, instead of transforming the result of `Arrays.toString`:

```
String resultString = IntStream.range(0, 3)
    .mapToObj(e -> rand.ints(3, 0, 5).mapToObj(Integer::toString)
                                     .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")))
    .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "[", "]"));
System.out.println(resultString);
```

though, in this case, you could also use

```
String resultString = IntStream.range(0, 3)
    .flatMap(e -> rand.ints(3, 0, 5))
    .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "[", "]"));
System.out.println(resultString);
```

or even

```
String resultString = rand.ints(3*3, 0, 5)
    .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "[", "]"));
System.out.println(resultString);
```

If you actually want the array, combine the second variant above with ``, but note that for most practical purposes, you may just use a `ThreadLocalRandom`:

```
String[] randomstrs = IntStream.range(0, 3)
    .mapToObj(e -> ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints(3, 0, 5)
        .mapToObj(Integer::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")))
    .toArray(String[]::new);
```